# Powershell http get request from jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

please tell me - how to run from jenkins (shell or windows powershell) powershell commando.
From command line the following command works.

```
powershell -command "[net.WebRequest]::Create(\"http://rackham:8080/job/MS-Enu-Deploy/buildWithParameters?ARTIFACT_VERSION=1.3\").GetResponse()"
```

This command I run from jenkins.
Build success, but get request is in post build section not fulfilled.

```
powershell -command "[net.WebRequest]::Create('http://rackham:8080/job/MS-Enu-Deploy/buildWithParameters?ARTIFACT_VERSION=1.3\').GetResponse()"
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks internal, so I can't hit the site you are referring. However, I would use PowerShell and use Invoke-WebRequest. I use this to grab data from websites and to do other various things. Try this and let me know if there is more that you need.

`$request = Invoke-WebRequest "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568695/powershell-http-get-request-from-jenkins"
$request.Content`

Comment: You got me a little misunderstood. I want not to get request. I want to send from one Jenkins to another Jenkins. The Http Request plugin is not suitable because it does not work with Jenkins variables.